# Python subprocess stdout to process stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdout, stdin

Edit: My main question is, is there some way for a subprocess's stdout to be non-exclusively piped into the process's stdin. Non-exclusively so that the keyboard still works. Both need to go into a raw_input prompt.

Context: I'm creating a python program that allows people who've bought tickets with qr codes entry at an event. The main part of the program is a raw_input() on loop that searches through a csv for a guest's name, email address or the unique hash that is embedded in the QR codes. I am trying to use zbarcam to scan in the unique hash. This *almost* works:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(["/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/ZBar/bin/zbarcam", "--raw"], stdout=PIPE)
```

That is, the QR code is scanned and the ticket hash pops up at the prompt so I can hit enter and have it search. The problem is zbarcam adds a newline so when I hit enter, it searches for a newline and returns everything in the csv. I can't find any way to strip the newline after the zbarcam output is piped to stdout (which enters into raw_input). Come to think of it, I can't even backspace or remove the newline using the keyboard. Do you know how to do that? I've done that sort of thing before, usually by copy-pasting an extra newline.

I added this line after the above ones:
   sys.stdin = p.stdout
and the QR code's newline was interpretd as an "enter" and the search process started, but it just took away my ability to type in a search term. Is there some way to have stdin routed to both of those?

Is there some other way I can get user input from a keyboard and from zbarcam?

Thanks in advance! I hope I sound coherant--been a long day.

Edit: if anyone wants to bash themselves in the head with this profoundly hacked-together code, they can have a look here https://github.com/rtwolf/qr-event-entry/blob/master/pulp_entry.py

Comment: After running the zbarcam process, why can't you just use: p.stdout.read().strip()?  That way you don't search for the newline and just the hash.

Comment: I think I understand. How do I get that back in to stdin for the raw_input prompt that is waiting for text? The idea is there's a prompt waiting for either a scanned QR code or text (like name/email address) to search for. I thought about temporarily switching sys.stdin to a StringIO but I can't do that without removing my ability to type a response into raw_input?

Comment: To get the hash as a bytestring: `unique_hash = subprocess.check_output(['/path/to/zbarcam', '--raw']).strip()` (if each scan requires to start a new `zbarcam` process). Otherwise you could use a reader thread to read hashes or `select.select()` if it works on p.stdout, sys.stdin in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! starting a new zbarcam process isn't possible cause it takes about 5 seconds to load up - 5 seconds per person is a lot when we've got 400 people come through the door. If I think I understand you correctly, the second option won't work for windows. :( I'm using cygwin if that makes a difference though...

Comment: Right now the best solution I can think of is to create two different versions of the script--one that accepts text search parameters and the other QR codes. Run each in its own cygwin window and switch between them based on what's coming in. They both write to the same csvs and long as they're both closed, it should be fine. How's that sound?

Comment: try whether [`select` can read from p.stdout in your environment](http://ideone.com/wm4ecF).

Comment: if `select` doesn't work; [you could try threads](http://ideone.com/WHrwMy).

Comment: Update: I decided to take a different tac. I ditched zbarcam and setup my old Nexus One as a barcode/qr code scanner using this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raz.scanner

So just created the one version that took in text entry and had the server program of the above app feed in the qr code's text and send a newline to check people in. It worked really well actually!

Thanks everyone for your help!